# Why is this awkward? "You're as quick to jump in as always."

Tags: grammar, prepositions, as

> You're ***as*** quick to jump in as always.

They say the natural way to say this is "You're quick to jump in as always" without the first as. But don't you use "as as" phrase like "This flower is ***as*** beautiful as the others"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You're quick to jump in as always.

This example is fine.

In this case, we are not using the as-as correlatve conjunction but the idiom *as always*.

> Definition of as always
> —used to say that something was expected because it always happens

> As always, dinner was delicious.

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/as%20always